# Some parts I don't understand

Tags: c#

C# code:

```
   using System;

    // this is the delegate declaration
    public delegate int Comparer(object obj1, object obj2);

    public class Name
    {
        public string FirstName = null;
        public string LastName = null;

        public Name(string first, string last)
        {
            FirstName = first;
            LastName = last;
        }

        // this is the delegate method handler
        public static int CompareFirstNames(object name1, object name2)
        {
            string n1 = ((Name)name1).FirstName;
            string n2 = ((Name)name2).FirstName;

            if (String.Compare(n1, n2) > 0)
            {
                return 1;
            }
            else if (String.Compare(n1, n2) < 0)
            {
                return -1;
            }
            else
            {
                return 0;
            }
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return FirstName + " " + LastName;
        }
    }

    class SimpleDelegate
    {
        Name[] names = new Name[5];

        public SimpleDelegate()
        {
            names[0] = new Name("Joe", "Mayo");
            names[1] = new Name("John", "Hancock");
            names[2] = new Name("Jane", "Doe");
            names[3] = new Name("John", "Doe");
            names[4] = new Name("Jack", "Smith");
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            SimpleDelegate sd = new SimpleDelegate();

            // this is the delegate instantiation
            Comparer cmp = new Comparer(Name.CompareFirstNames);

            Console.WriteLine("\nBefore Sort: \n");

            sd.PrintNames();

            // observe the delegate argument
            sd.Sort(cmp);

            Console.WriteLine("\nAfter Sort: \n");

            sd.PrintNames();
        }

        // observe  the delegate parameter
        public void Sort(Comparer compare)
        {
            object temp;

            for (int i=0; i < names.Length; i++)
            {
                for (int j=i; j < names.Length; j++)
                {
                    // using delegate "compare" just like
                    // a normal method
                    if ( compare(names[i], names[j]) > 0 )
                    {
                        temp = names[i];
                        names[i] = names[j];
                        names[j] = (Name)temp;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        public void PrintNames()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Names: \n");

            foreach (Name name in names)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(name.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
```

There are two parts of the code that I don't understand at all. What do these parts exactly do, (respectively); and what subject(s) do I need to learn to understand these parts?

```
string n1 = ((Name)name1).FirstName;
```

What does ((Name)name1) do?

```
public void Sort(Comparer compare)
```

Can anyone provide any tips or feedback on how those parts of the code function? Can you possibly lead me into the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

First: `string n1 = ((Name)name1).FirstName`

- `(Name)name1` which can be written generically as `(Type)variable`. What this does is take the variable and attempt to cast (a synonym would be convert) the variable `name1` into the type `Name`. This then allows us to access the `FirstName` property.
- Learn more here: https://www.w3schools.com/cs/cs_type_casting.asp

Second: `public void Sort(Comparer compare)`

This is a method declaration.

- `public` indicates the accessibility. Other options include `private`, `protected` and a few others. `public` indicates that this method can be called by any code that has a reference to an instance of this object.
- `void` indicates the return type. `void` is a special keyword to mean that no value is returned from the method.
- `Sort` is the method name
- `Compare compare`: `Compare` is the type of the parameter to be passed in and `compare` is the name of the parameter which can be used throughout the method.
- Learn more here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/methods